# How to check if CSV file is not used by other process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, python-watchdog

I'm having a Sensor with me that Sense the data and accumulate it and put it into a CSV file at a regular interval of time ( Every time a new CSV file is been made).

I am using watchdog API to put a watch on a newly generated CSV file. Every time I try to read the newly generate CSV file using pandas "read_csv()" function but somehow I am not able to read the file. I came to know that this is happening because my sensors are creating the temporary file first as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

I think that the pandas read_csv() function is not able to read the file until its completely closed after putting sensor data into it.

Any suggestions on how to read the CSV file? Or like checking if the file has been closed completely.

My Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from Append_Function import append_df_to_excel
import time


class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    newDataFrameSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(pd.DataFrame)


class Watcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.watch_dir = os.getcwd()
    self.directory_to_watch = None
    self.emitter = Emitter()
    self.observer = Observer()
    self.event_handler = Handler(
        emitter=self.emitter,
        patterns=["*.CSV"],
        ignore_patterns=["*.tmp"],
        ignore_directories=True
    )

def set_filename(self, filename):
    self.directory_to_watch = os.path.join(self.watch_dir, filename)

def run(self):
    self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.directory_to_watch, recursive=False)
    self.observer.start()

def stop_watcher(self):
    self.observer.stop()


class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
def __init__(self, *args, emitter=None, **kwargs):
    super(Handler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._emitter = emitter
    self.file_name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+".xlsx"

def on_any_event(self, event):
    done_flag = False
    if event.is_directory:
        return None
    elif event.event_type == 'created':
        # Take any action here when a file is first created.
        print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)

        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name)):
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path)
                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                       pd.read_csv(event.src_path, index_col=0))
                self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
                df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)

            except Exception as e:
                print("File not ready", e)
        else:
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path)
                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, index_col=0))
                self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
                df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)

            except Exception as e:
                print("File not ready", e)

    elif event.event_type == 'modified':
        print("Modified created event - %s." % event.src_path)

        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path)
            append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                               pd.read_csv(event.src_path, index_col=0))
            self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
            df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)

        except Exception as e:
            print("File not ready", e)
    else:

        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path)
            append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                               pd.read_csv(event.src_path, index_col=0))
            self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
            df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)

        except Exception as e:
            print("File not ready", e)


class DataFrameTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(pd.DataFrame)
def append_dataframe(self, df):
    df = df.copy()
    df = df.astype('float64', errors='ignore')
    df = df.round(decimals=2)
    if df.columns.size > self.columnCount():
        self.setColumnCount(df.columns.size)
    r = self.rowCount()
    if r == 0:
        self.insertRow(r)
        for c, column in enumerate(df):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(column)
            self.setItem(r, c, it)
    i = self.rowCount()
    for r, row in df.iterrows():
        self.insertRow(self.rowCount())
        for c, (column, value) in enumerate(row.iteritems()):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
            self.setItem(i + r, c, it)
```

Comment: Yes you may be readinig it before it is closed - have you tried creating the file in the correct directory but with a name that won’t be seen by the watcher (I.e. without the .csv extension) then once closed renaming it so it is already complete when the watcher sees it?

Comment: @barny No, I didn't. Let me try and I'll let you know.

Comment: @barny Same Error "File not ready [Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/viral/Desktop/Sample\\998_20190420T060513.txt' does not exist: b'C:/Users/viral/Desktop/Sample\\998_20190420T060513.txt'
" I change the file from CSV to TXT then I dropped in Directory and then I changed the extension from TXT to CSV and i got the above mentiond error.

Comment: Your code should’t be trying to read a .txt file. Please edit the _full_ error message into your question. And change all those `except Exception as e` so they `raise` rather than continuing which is most likely hiding the real error.